# non-even continuous real function orthogonal to sin(nx) for every n

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

is there an example of a **non-even** real $2\pi$-periodic continuous function $f(x)$ such that $$\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}f(x)\cdot sin(nx)dx = 0$$ for every $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

I can easily construct a non-continuous example, and I managed to put up a proof that such a function cannot exist if $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable using convergence of the Fourier series.

Comment: Modulo null sets, every square-integrable $2\pi$-periodic function orthogonal to all $x\mapsto \sin (nx)$ is even.

Comment: what do you mean by 'modulo null sets'?

Comment: You can arbitrarily change a function on a null set (set of measure $0$) without affecting integrals. So you can for example take the characteristic function of $1 + \pi\mathbb{Q}$. This is not an even function, but from the perspective of the Lebesgue integral, it's equivalent to the zero function, which is even. Thus, a class in $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ is orthogonal to all $\sin (nx)$ if and only if it has an even representative.

Comment: I didn't study Lebesgue integrals yet, so I'll have to take your word for it. Do you by any chance have an idea of how to approach proving this without using Lebesgue integrals?

Comment: If you're using the Riemann integral, it's similar. Up to changes that don't affect any integral, such a function must be even. If you want such a function to be continuous, it must be even, as follows for example from [Fejér's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r's_theorem).

Comment: Oh, that answers my question. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can arbitrarily change a function on a null set (set of measure 0) without affecting integrals. So you can for example take the characteristic function of 1+πQ. This is not an even function, but from the perspective of the Lebesgue integral, it's equivalent to the zero function, which is even. Thus, a class in L2([−π,π]) is orthogonal to all sin(nx) if and only if it has an even representative.
>
> If you're using the Riemann integral, it's similar. Up to changes that don't affect any integral, such a function must be even. If you want such a function to be continuous, it must be even, as follows for example from Fejér's theorem.

Thanks Daniel Fischer for the answer!